# How to make postgresql query by passing php array of strings, tricking with double-quotes?

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

I am passing array to postgresql in "WHERE" clause. but php is returning strings with double-quotes that postgrsql uses to define column. So postgresql is using the strings values as columns.

```
$allowed_A = \App\NewA::selectRaw("replace(unaccent(trim(name)), ' ', '') as newname")
   ->whereRaw('replace(unaccent(trim(name)), \' \', \'\') IN ("'.implode(",", $allowed_A).'")')->get();
```

Getting :

> Undefined column: 7 ERROR: column "Purchase,Sale,...

How to fix it?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your expression encloses the values in double quotes. Change it to this:

```php
$A = \App\NewA::selectRaw("replace(unaccent(trim(name)), ' ', '') as newname")
->whereRaw("replace(unaccent(trim(name)), ' ', '') IN ('".implode("','", $allowed_A)."')")->get();
```

Pls. bear in mind that your approach is prone to sql injection.